SQL Server Insert using SQLAlchemy in Python
I am trying to insert a table of 500 k rows into a SQL Server Database on a Streamlit app.
When I do this on the app it does not take too much time however when 2 users do the insert (into different tables based of their username) the insert sometimes stops for one of the users.
I am not sure if this is due to Streamlit or the insert statement taking too much time, in any case here is the code:
note : uploadtable is the uploaded data in a pandas dataframe
if st.button("upload data"):    
    
# Construct the connection URL
    
    engine = create_engine(connection_url)
    
    # Create a metadata object
    metadata = MetaData()
    
    # Define table structure
    submission = Table(username, metadata,
                    Column('id', String),
                    Column('premium', Float)
                    )


    metadata.create_all(engine)
    
    # Insert data from DataFrame into the SQL table
    uploadtable.to_sql(username, engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
    st.write("Submission was uploaded")

Is there any way to speed this up or refine the code to be more efficient when multiple users does an insert?

Do you have indexes/keys on the table to support the existence check?

Hi Dan, Thank you for your reply :-)
No so the tables gets drop and recreated (to have the user's latest submission)
Would it be better to truncate the tables and add an index ? or should I alter the existence check?

An index is needed to avoid a full table scan for the existence check on insert, improving performance.

Your current code ensures that the table always exists when .to_sql() is called, so if_exists='replace' will cause .to_sql() to always drop that table and re-create it, placing DDL locks on the system tables while .to_sql() is executing. If you want the same effect as "truncate table if exists" you can do metadata.drop_all(engine) before metadata.create_all(engine) and then use .to_sql(…, if_exists='append')
